# How to convert JSON array of key-value pairs to JSON object?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, python-2.7, simplejson

I get the data like below from the website:

```
{
  ...
  u'rows':[
    [
      u'mail@example.com',
      u'74'
    ],
    [
      u'mail2@example.com',
      u'1'
    ],
    [
      u'mail3@example.com',
      u'1'
    ],
    ...
  ],
```

I've shown just the data I need. How can I convert it to json like:

```
{u'mail@example.com': 74, u'mail2@example.com': 1, u'mail3@example.com': 1, ...}
```

I can read elements one by one:

```
if response.get('rows'):
    total = 0
    for row in response.get('rows'):
        total += int(row[1])
        logging.info(row[0]+": "+row[1])
```

But not sure what should be done next. Don't think I should generate just the string.

Comment: You *shouldn't* generate the JSON manually. Create the relevant *Python structure* (i.e. dictionary, using a transformation), and then let your JSON library turn it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a dict and populate it with the content of the rows:

```
d = {}
for row in response.get('rows'):
    d[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Then, if you want a json string representation:

```
json.dumps(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
>>> first_json = { 'rows':[['mail@example.com', '74'],['mail2@example.com','1'],['mail3@example.com','1']]}
>>> second_json = {item[0]: item[1] for item in first_json['rows']}
>>> second_json
{'mail@example.com': '74', 'mail2@example.com': '1', 'mail3@example.com': '1'}
>>>
```

You will have to load the above data string as a `json` using `loads()`. `first_json` assumes that it is available to it as a json object. Then after computing the `second_json` as above, use the `dumps()` on `second_json` to get the output json

**EDIT**

Looks like you are computing total number of emails for a particular email. In that case I would use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_json = defaultdict(int)
for item in first_json['rows']:
    second_json[item[0]] += int(item[1])
```

Then print out the `second_json` as explained above.

Comment: more a dict than a json

Answer (score 0):

```
bbb = {}
aaa = {
   u'rows':[
    [
      u'mail@example.com',
      u'74'
    ],
    [
      u'mail2@example.com',
      u'1'
    ],
    [
      u'mail3@example.com',
      u'1'
    ],
  ],
}

for item in aaa['rows']:
    bbb[item[0]] = item[1]

print bbb

>>> {u'mail@example.com': u'74', u'mail2@example.com': u'1', u'mail3@example.com': u'1'}
```